# Conditional logic and loops: How can I get this working correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to only email the PDFs, created from a Google Sheet, in a drive folder that have not yet been emailed. My strategy thus far has been to create a key ("printed" although for simplicity I should probably rename this variable to emailed.) that changes from a blank to 1 when the if statement runs, thus making it skip over it the next time the code runs. My issue at the moment is that the code runs and sends an email for every row in the Sheet, regardless of what is in the "printed" column. I suspect this is an issue with either the variable type or the logical operator as I am very much a novice at JS (my expertise is Python and VB.Net unfortunately.)

I thank you all for your consideration. Let me know if there is any questions I can clear up.

```
function createBulkPDFs() {
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1zGTNkzUr_ApaYSpqdu_PKcEuDrVm9r9kA_oyqfIRWeI");
  const TempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1h8RHp890f0HGsc-dulwEP9Urrpnq7xcw");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1boy1E2Ih3Cp3zMTak8nAUtmtc7e34Y1L");
  const currentSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WorkOrders");
  
  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,11).getDisplayValues();
  
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    var printed = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 11).getDisplayValue();
    console.log(printed)
    if (printed !== 1) {
      var ID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 11).setValue(getRndInteger(1000,50000));
      console.log(ID)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 11).setValue(1); }
      createPDF(row[2], row[3], row[0], row[4], row[1], row[5],row[8], row[6], row[9], docFile, TempFolder, pdfFolder);
      var ID = row[9]
      console.log(ID)
      var file = pdfFolder.getFilesByName(ID)
      MailApp.sendEmail("fakeEmail@gmail.com","New Work Order", "Please find the Work Order PDF attached to this email. \n\n This is an automated message, please do not respond.", {name:   ID, attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 11).setValue(1); }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement ends at this line, so `sendMail` is executed regardless of the value of `printed`

```js
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 11).setValue(1); }
```

---

Besides, you should better do batch operations with [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)